# Strange behavior after relaunching an iOS app after termination

Tags: ios, background-process, httpserver

I'm developing an in-house iOS app that requires an HTTP Server to be running all the time.

To do so, I use a background task to keep my application alive (playing audio in the background), and then I start the HTTP server. This is the code from my `AppDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    bgTask = [[MyBackgroundTask alloc] init];
    [bgTask startBackgroundTaskWithTarget:self selector:@selector(backgroundCallback:)];

    httpServer = [[HTTPServer alloc] init];
    httpServer.interface = @"localhost";    
    [httpServer setType:@"_http._tcp."];
    [httpServer setPort:8080];
    [httpServer start];
}
```

And it works perfectly... almost!

Sometimes, the application, while running in the background, is being killed. For example:

```
Jun 24 11:27:24 My-iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.test.MyApp[0x668d]' was killed by jetsam.
```

And *obviously* the HTTP Server goes down. But when I relaunch the app after this termination, the HTTP Server won't start! (When I type `localhost:8080` in Safari, I see an error message).

I don't have a problem with termination, that's completely okay. But I want my HTTP Server to be up and running when I reopen the app. But why that does not happen?

(Please note that if I close the app myself, everything works good).

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to restart the web server?  Is it *Address already in use* by any chance?

Comment: No error messages! The log files even say: `Started HTTP Server on port 8080.`
But I can see that the `backgroundCallback` is not being called anymore (in normal situations, it prints something to the console every 2 seconds).

Comment: I don't *restart* the web server separately. All is done is through `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

> Be prepared to handle connection failures in your network-based sockets. The system may tear down socket connections while your app is suspended for any number of reasons. As long as your socket-based code is prepared for other types of network failures, such as a lost signal or network transition, this should not lead to any unusual problems. When your app resumes, if it encounters a failure upon using a socket, simply reestablish the connection.

or any other reasons from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: The main problem is that I can hardly reproduce this bug. Is there anyway to kill the app by Jetsam?